# Css no se aplica en mi main ni en mi header usando bootstrap4

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Edit: sigue sin funcionar.
Necesito vuestra ayuda urgentemente. Estoy haciendo mi segundo html en una web y estoy conservando el navbar y el footer de la principal. El caso es, que el css que tiene propiedades de estos usadas en el index de mi web, se aplica en esas dos secciones pero al intentar modificar elementos del main o del body, no se modifican en su totalidad, como por ejemplo el font-type. Llevo 3 horas intentando tocar el problema y ya no se si es del bootstrap o de que pero necesito resolverlo pronto ya que queria meterle una funcionalidad especifica por javascript siguiendo un tutorial pero ni siquiera funciona esto. Gracias de antemano y espero que me podais ayudar!!!!! 
Pd:El css que no se aplica empieza en la linea 177 y el problema del html es del header y del main.
Edito: Tambien he probado a cambiar el orden de mi css respecto a la de bootstrap.

```js
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

gsap.utils.toArray('.segmento').forEach(section => {
  ScrollTrigger.create({
    trigger: section,
    start: 'top top',
    pin: true,
    pinSpacing: false
  });
});
AOS.init({
        offset: 400, // offset (in px) from the original trigger point
        delay: 0, // values from 0 to 3000, with step 50ms
        duration: 1000 // values from 0 to 3000, with step 50ms
      });
```

```css
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.navbar-nav>li {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

nav {
    background-color: #000033;
    opacity: 0.95;
}

.cookie-container {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #2f3640;
    color: #f5f6fa;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    box-shadow: 0 -2px 16px rgba(47, 54, 64, 0.151);
    transition: 400ms;
}

.cookie-container a {
    color: #f5f6fa;
}

.cookie-container.active {
    bottom: 0;
}

.cookie-btn {
    background: #e84118;
    border: 0;
    color: #f5f6fa;
    padding: 12px 48px;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.column-right {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 2rem;
}

.column-left {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0rem 2rem;
}

.column-left h1 {
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-style: italic;
}

.column-left p {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    line-height: 1.1;
}

.segmento {
    background: #66488f;
}

footer {
    margin: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: sticky;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000033;
    padding: 50px;
    font-size: 14px;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    height: 10vh;
}

.footer-left img {
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 150px;
    max-height: 60px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.socials {
    text-align: center;
}

.footer>* {
    flex: 1 100%;
}

.footer-left {
    margin-right: 1.25em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.footer-right {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.footer-right>* {
    flex: 1 50%;
    margin-right: 1.25em;
}

.box a {
    color: #999;
}

.footer-bottom {
    text-align: center;
    color: #999;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.footer-left p {
    padding-right: 20%;
    color: #999;
}

.socials a {
    background: #364a62;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .footer-right>* {
        flex: 1;
    }
    .footer-left {
        flex: 1 0px;
    }
    .footer-right {
        flex: 2 0px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .footer {
        padding: 15px;
    }
}

.btninicio {
    position: fixed;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #6F1E51;
    bottom: 40px;
    right: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.footer h2 {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.footer ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.footer li {
    line-height: 2em;
}

.footer a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    background: #f9f9f9;
}

a {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0 2rem;
}

.main-header {
    height: 55vh;
    padding: 2rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.main-header h1 {
    font-size: 4rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    line-height: 1.2;
}

.main-header h1 span {
    color: #b50d10;
}

.main-header p {
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.card {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 2rem;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.card h3 {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.card img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}

.card>div {
    padding: 2rem;
}

.card:nth-child(even) img {
    order: 2;
}

@media(max-width:600px) {
    .card {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.css" \>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.4/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="histo.css">

    <title>History</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="log.png" />
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark  sticky-top">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SneakerReport</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="ini.html"> <i class="fa fa-home"></i> Inicio <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="histo.html"> <i class="fa fa-book"></i> Historia</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Inscribete</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-certificate"></i>
                        Marcas
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Supreme <i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Palace <i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <header class="main-header">
        <h1><span>Acrylic Painting</span> Gallery</h1>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias,
            quam!
        </p>
    </header>
    <main class="container">
        <section class="card">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/VvC0vpN/paint-1.png" alt="" />
            <div>
                <h3>Acrylic Painting One</h3>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod error
                    enim laudantium, animi veniam libero eveniet culpa unde perferendis
                    illo fugit corporis, voluptatibus totam dolorum, maiores magnam
                    officia. Ab, delectus.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn">Buy Now</a>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="card" data-aos="fade-left">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/3NHjDcW/paint-2.png" alt="" />
            <div>
                <h3>Acrylic Painting Two</h3>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod error
                    enim laudantium, animi veniam libero eveniet culpa unde perferendis
                    illo fugit corporis, voluptatibus totam dolorum, maiores magnam
                    officia. Ab, delectus.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn">Buy Now</a>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="card" data-aos="fade-right">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/0VywMkW/paint-3.png" alt="" />
            <div>
                <h3>Acrylic Painting Three</h3>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod error
                    enim laudantium, animi veniam libero eveniet culpa unde perferendis
                    illo fugit corporis, voluptatibus totam dolorum, maiores magnam
                    officia. Ab, delectus.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn">Buy Now</a>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="card" data-aos="fade-left">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/5LkJFRP/paint-4.png" alt="" />
            <div>
                <h3>Acrylic Painting Four</h3>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod error
                    enim laudantium, animi veniam libero eveniet culpa unde perferendis
                    illo fugit corporis, voluptatibus totam dolorum, maiores magnam
                    officia. Ab, delectus.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn">Buy Now</a>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="card" data-aos="fade-right">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/61R8Q2y/paint-5.png" alt="" />
            <div>
                <h3>Acrylic Painting Five</h3>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod error
                    enim laudantium, animi veniam libero eveniet culpa unde perferendis
                    illo fugit corporis, voluptatibus totam dolorum, maiores magnam
                    officia. Ab, delectus.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn">Buy Now</a>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
    <footer class="footer segmento cuatro" style="bottom:0">
        <div class="footer-left">
            <img src="yzy.png" alt="snk">
            <p>SneakerReport nace como una solucion para que gente de todas las edades tenga una posibilidad
                de acceder a moda limitada sin pagar reventa.</p>
            <div class="socials">
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100011277759449" target="_blank"><i class=" fab fa-facebook"></i> </a>
                <a href="https://twitter.com/Gonzaacdz" target="_blank"><i class=" fab fa-twitter"></i> </a>
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/gx.neee/?hl=es" target="_blank"><i class=" fab fa-instagram"></i> </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="footer-right">
            <li>
                <h2>Paginas en las que tenemos soporte</h2>
                <ul class="box">
                    <li><a href="#"> Supreme </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Palace </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h2>Otras secciones</h2>
                <ul class="box">
                    <li><a href="histo.html"> Historia </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Inscribete </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h2>Direccion</h2>
                <ul class="box">
                    <li> Avenida de los Rosales, 99 </li>
                    <li> Piso 1º Puerta B </li>
                    <li> Madrid, ES, 28021 </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="footer-bottom">
            <p>Todos los derechos reservados a &copy;Gonzalo Canteli 2020 </p>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <a class="btninicio" href="#"> <i class=" fas fa-angle-double-up"></i> </a>
    <div class="cookie-container">
        <p>Utilizamos cookies propias y de terceros para mejorar la experiencia del usuario a través de su navegación. Si continúas navegando aceptas su uso. <a href="#">Política de cookies. </a></p>
        <button class="cookie-btn">
            De acuerdo
        </button>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.5.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.5.1/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.js"></script>
    <script>
        AOS.init();
    </script>
    <script src="cookieplugin.js"></script>
    <script src="histo.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Captura de como aparece @Excorpion   :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como debería de verse:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Claro, pero aun cambiando el orden no me funciona

Comment: Si intentas con `!important` ¿los estilos siguen sin aplicarse?

Comment: ¿Estás limpiando la memoria *caché* del navegador antes de intentar ver los cambios?

Comment: un punto importante es el como ordenas la incrustación de los css pero también el si estas ocupando la ruta de bootstrap o estas usando una copia local

https://blog.hubspot.com/website/how-to-override-bootstrap-css

Comment: He intentado ambas cosas, solo cambia si lo edito directamente desde el html con style="" y me sorprende que solo se aplique al footer y al nav y no a todo el resto

Comment: @Wazabi especificame que estilo no se aplica para revisarlo, a mi me ha cambiado todo solo con cambiar el orden.

Comment: Como dice @MauricioContreras puede que sea problema del caché de tu navegador, intenta borrarlo y recargar la página.

Comment: No se esta aplicando el estilo que se aplica al body, es decir la fuente, el color, los padding etc ni casi ninguno, solo parece que se aplica lo referido a container. Por cierto soy un novato en esto por si hay algo mal ordenado o mal escrito, pero queria incluir una funcionalidad de java siguiendo un video de yt pero ni siquiera siguiendo su codigo exacto funciona. Puedo aportar link

Comment: La cache tampoco cambia nada :(

Comment: Una sugerencia, los estilos de Bootstrap u otras librerías o frameworks no deberías modificarlos. Si necesitas modificar alguno de ellos, crea tu propio estilo, lo agregas al final de la lista de estilos tanto en la forma en que lo vinculas al documento como en la forma en que lo usas en el elemento. Si tienes un cambio al estilo de `container-fluid` por ejemplo, escribes tu propio cambio: `my-container-fluid`. Luego al elemento le aplicas los estilos en orden: `<div class="container-fluid my-container-fluid"></div>`. Por eso se llama **C**ascade **S**tyle **S**heets. Saludos

Comment: @JuanRivera apuntando esta creo, porque si borro la referencia el navbar desaparece

Comment: @MauricioContreras aun asi, si le añado una nueva clase no parece modificarse, ya que he probado a incluir el main y el header en un div con una clase personalizada y aun asi no funcionaba

Comment: @Excorpion he seguido esto: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ptfUwPJbGlQ&list=LL&index=9&ab_channel=TraversyMedia Si lo necesitas puedo aportar mi index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo único que debes hacer es asegurarte de que tus estilos personalizados se carguen después de los de *bootstrap* y funciona correctamente.

```js
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

gsap.utils.toArray('.segmento').forEach(section => {
  ScrollTrigger.create({
    trigger: section,
    start: 'top top',
    pin: true,
    pinSpacing: false
  });
});
AOS.init({
        offset: 400, // offset (in px) from the original trigger point
        delay: 0, // values from 0 to 3000, with step 50ms
        duration: 1000 // values from 0 to 3000, with step 50ms
      });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.css" \>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.4/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="histo.css">

    <title>History</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="log.png" />
<style>
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.navbar-nav>li {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

nav {
    background-color: #000033;
    opacity: 0.95;
}

.cookie-container {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #2f3640;
    color: #f5f6fa;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    box-shadow: 0 -2px 16px rgba(47, 54, 64, 0.151);
    transition: 400ms;
}

.cookie-container a {
    color: #f5f6fa;
}

.cookie-container.active {
    bottom: 0;
}

.cookie-btn {
    background: #e84118;
    border: 0;
    color: #f5f6fa;
    padding: 12px 48px;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.column-right {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 2rem;
}

.column-left {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0rem 2rem;
}

.column-left h1 {
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-style: italic;
}

.column-left p {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
    line-height: 1.1;
}

.segmento {
    background: #66488f;
}

footer {
    margin: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: sticky;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000033;
    padding: 50px;
    font-size: 14px;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    height: 10vh;
}

.footer-left img {
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 150px;
    max-height: 60px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.socials {
    text-align: center;
}

.footer>* {
    flex: 1 100%;
}

.footer-left {
    margin-right: 1.25em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.footer-right {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.footer-right>* {
    flex: 1 50%;
    margin-right: 1.25em;
}

.box a {
    color: #999;
}

.footer-bottom {
    text-align: center;
    color: #999;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.footer-left p {
    padding-right: 20%;
    color: #999;
}

.socials a {
    background: #364a62;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .footer-right>* {
        flex: 1;
    }
    .footer-left {
        flex: 1 0px;
    }
    .footer-right {
        flex: 2 0px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .footer {
        padding: 15px;
    }
}

.btninicio {
    position: fixed;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #6F1E51;
    bottom: 40px;
    right: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.footer h2 {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.footer ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.footer li {
    line-height: 2em;
}

.footer a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    background: #f9f9f9;
}

a {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0 2rem;
}

.main-header {
    height: 55vh;
    padding: 2rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.main-header h1 {
    font-size: 4rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    line-height: 1.2;
}

.main-header h1 span {
    color: #b50d10;
}

.main-header p {
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.card {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 2rem;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.card h3 {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.card img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}

.card>div {
    padding: 2rem;
}

.card:nth-child(even) img {
    order: 2;
}

@media(max-width:600px) {
    .card {
        display: block;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark  sticky-top">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SneakerReport</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="ini.html"> <i class="fa fa-home"></i> Inicio <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="histo.html"> <i class="fa fa-book"></i> Historia</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Inscribete</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-certificate"></i>
                        Marcas
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Supreme <i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i></a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Palace <i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <header class="main-header">
        <h1><span>Acrylic Painting</span> Gallery</h1>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias,
            quam!
        </p>
    </header>
    <main class="container">
        <section class="card">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/VvC0vpN/paint-1.png" alt="" />
            <div>
                <h3>Acrylic Painting One</h3>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod error
                    enim laudantium, animi veniam libero eveniet culpa unde perferendis
                    illo fugit corporis, voluptatibus totam dolorum, maiores magnam
                    officia. Ab, delectus.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn">Buy Now</a>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="card" data-aos="fade-left">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/3NHjDcW/paint-2.png" alt="" />
            <div>
                <h3>Acrylic Painting Two</h3>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod error
                    enim laudantium, animi veniam libero eveniet culpa unde perferendis
                    illo fugit corporis, voluptatibus totam dolorum, maiores magnam
                    officia. Ab, delectus.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn">Buy Now</a>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="card" data-aos="fade-right">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/0VywMkW/paint-3.png" alt="" />
            <div>
                <h3>Acrylic Painting Three</h3>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod error
                    enim laudantium, animi veniam libero eveniet culpa unde perferendis
                    illo fugit corporis, voluptatibus totam dolorum, maiores magnam
                    officia. Ab, delectus.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn">Buy Now</a>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section class="card" data-aos="fade-left">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/5LkJFRP/paint-4.png" alt="" />
            <div>
                <h3>Acrylic Painting Four</h3>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod error
                    enim laudantium, animi veniam libero eveniet culpa unde perferendis
                    illo fugit corporis, voluptatibus totam dolorum, maiores magnam
                    officia. Ab, delectus.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn">Buy Now</a>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="card" data-aos="fade-right">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/61R8Q2y/paint-5.png" alt="" />
            <div>
                <h3>Acrylic Painting Five</h3>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod error
                    enim laudantium, animi veniam libero eveniet culpa unde perferendis
                    illo fugit corporis, voluptatibus totam dolorum, maiores magnam
                    officia. Ab, delectus.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn">Buy Now</a>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
    <footer class="footer segmento cuatro" style="bottom:0">
        <div class="footer-left">
            <img src="yzy.png" alt="snk">
            <p>SneakerReport nace como una solucion para que gente de todas las edades tenga una posibilidad
                de acceder a moda limitada sin pagar reventa.</p>
            <div class="socials">
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100011277759449" target="_blank"><i class=" fab fa-facebook"></i> </a>
                <a href="https://twitter.com/Gonzaacdz" target="_blank"><i class=" fab fa-twitter"></i> </a>
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/gx.neee/?hl=es" target="_blank"><i class=" fab fa-instagram"></i> </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="footer-right">
            <li>
                <h2>Paginas en las que tenemos soporte</h2>
                <ul class="box">
                    <li><a href="#"> Supreme </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Palace </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h2>Otras secciones</h2>
                <ul class="box">
                    <li><a href="histo.html"> Historia </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Inscribete </a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h2>Direccion</h2>
                <ul class="box">
                    <li> Avenida de los Rosales, 99 </li>
                    <li> Piso 1º Puerta B </li>
                    <li> Madrid, ES, 28021 </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="footer-bottom">
            <p>Todos los derechos reservados a &copy;Gonzalo Canteli 2020 </p>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <a class="btninicio" href="#"> <i class=" fas fa-angle-double-up"></i> </a>
    <div class="cookie-container">
        <p>Utilizamos cookies propias y de terceros para mejorar la experiencia del usuario a través de su navegación. Si continúas navegando aceptas su uso. <a href="#">Política de cookies. </a></p>
        <button class="cookie-btn">
            De acuerdo
        </button>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.5.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.5.1/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.js"></script>
    <script>
        AOS.init();
    </script>
    <script src="cookieplugin.js"></script>
    <script src="histo.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

En el fragmento de código la única opción para lograrlo es colocar los estilos antes de `</head>`, pero en tu proyecto solo necesitas colocar la etiqueta después de todos los otros CSS necesarios.

Comment: Lo unico que ahora pierdo el footer y el efecto. Alguna pista para arreglar eso?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con _"pierdo el footer y el efecto"_?